# HTML - Change maximum rows on a select tag multiple

Tags: javascript, html, select

So how can I change how many rows a select tag with multiple enabled should be showed:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

This will only show the first four options how can I show the fifth without have to scroll?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use CSS to specify the exact height, but this will probably not render exactly the same across all browsers due to different rendering of the select:

```
<select multiple="multiple" style="height: 24pt">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24Myw/

Answer (score 107):

Use the `size` attribute:

```
<select size="5" multiple name="whatever">
```

References:

- [`<select>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/select).

Comment: Given that you explicitly state you want to show five rows, I'm not sure I understand your problem?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see an alternative, at the moment (though I'm unused to this behaviour).

Answer (score 3):

```
<select size="any number" name="#" id="#">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

it working well

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit more of a dynamic solution using JavaScript:

```
// put your select into a variable for faster reference.
var mySelect = document.getElementById("my_select");
//decide on the maximum number of options you want displayed and store it in a variable.
//that makes it easier to change if you change your mind on the max or if you want a more dynamic max.
var maxOptions = 5;
// if you have maxOptions or fewer options.
if(mySelect.options.length <= maxOptions){ 
    //set your select size to your option length.
    mySelect.size = mySelect.options.length; 
}else{
    // if you have more than maxOptions options, set your select size to maxOptions.
    mySelect.size = maxOptions;
}
```

**NB!** Note that the "multiple" attribute does not just show more than 1 option, it also makes you able to select more than one option!

Comment: Sometimes one needs a way to display multiple lines but allow only a single selection. Does anybody know a direct way to do that without using JavaScript widgets? In other words, the multi-line display and multi-line selection should be separate independent features, it seems to me. One is a visual feature, the other a domain (data) feature. They somehow got bundled together in the HTML standard.

Comment: @FloverOwe I'm thinking something akin to setting the selected option to e.target, or just disabling the shift button keydown event would do it. I have not made the experiment to back that claim up, yet.